# Create a list of dictionaries from host groups in ansible playbook

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I want to dynamically create a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[ {'host': 'hostname1', 'id': 1}, {'host': 'hostname2', 'id': 2}, ]
```

And assign it to a variable in my playbook.

This variable is needed for a role I am using.

My attempt is the following:

```
- hosts:
   - some-hosts
  vars:
    zk_hosts: []
  tasks:
    - name: create my var
      set_fact:
        zk_hosts: "{{ zk_hosts + [ {'host': item.1, 'id': item.0} ] }}"
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups.some-hosts }}"
```

However, when I run the playbook I have this warning:

```
 [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from stack.yml, line 16, column 3, found a duplicate dict key (vars).  Using last defined value only.
```

And and error at this play:

```
fatal: [192.168.0.21]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'zk_hosts' is undefined"}
```

If I don't define `zk_hosts` before trying to set the fact, I get an error that the variable is undefined.

How can I solve?

---

**EDIT**

Easy fix, I just defined `zk_hosts` within the same task...

```
  tasks:
    - name: create my var
      vars:
        zk_hosts: []
      set_fact:
        zk_hosts: "{{ zk_hosts + [ {'host': item.1, 'id': item.0} ] }}"
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups.some-hosts }}"
```

**Anyway, if there is a less cumbersome way of achieving the same, please advise!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use default filter:

```
set_fact:
  zk_hosts: "{{ zk_hosts|default([]) + [ {'host': item.1, 'id': item.0} ] }}"
with_indexed_items: "{{ groups.some-hosts }}"
```